# iOS - Memory usage constantly grows even though no memory leaks shown for actual app (SpriteKit App)

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, sprite-kit, instruments

I have a sprite kit game I am building and am nearing completion, so I started profiling the app to make sure I had no memory leaks, etc to improve performance.

I noticed that my memory usage grows about 1mb per second when I run the app :
[image]

So I started running Instruments, and am not too familiar with using it, but from what I have gathered from tutorials online is that the main thing to pay attention to is the number of persistent allocated objects to ensure that objects you expect to be deallocated are actually deallocated (i.e. enemies you destroyed, bullets that are removed from scene, etc). Instruments does show the expected number of persistent / transient (deallocated) objects throughout the app life cycle but also huge numbers of memory leaks are being reported (~2000 every 10-20 seconds - not sure if from other apps on device or my app):

[image]

Here is another image of the Memory Leaks (without filtering my app name - so not sure if its my app that is responsible or not):

[image]

If I let the app run for a long period of time, 10+ minutes, it eventually crashes due to:

```
Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue
```

Any suggestions on how to figure out whats going on? Are the reported ~2000 memory leaks actually from my app? Am I missing something in Instruments?

Comment: Your title says there are no leaks shown but instruments says there is thousands of leaks?

Comment: @dan Sorry, meant no leaks are being shown for the app itself. Updated title. Thanks.

Comment: As you can see, this is something to think about from the start, not when you are *finished* your app. Overriding deinits and designing relationships between objects is a measure to prevent this. You should override every deinit of classes you've made and use weak / unowned references where appropriate. So there is no silver bullet for this, but rather go through all of your code and search for retain cycles. Retain cycle happens when instance A has a strong reference to instance B , and instance B has a strong reference to instance A. In short, to break this cycle, make one reference *weak*.

Comment: @Whirlwind Sorry for the misleading info, I had thought about this the entire time I was developing the app, but I didn't profile it frequently. I don't believe my issue is a retain-cycle. Right now I disabled pretty much everything (enemy generation, background scrolling, music, code in update() method, etc.) and the app still steadily increases memory roughly .5mb per second. And all its doing is showing a player sitting at the bottom of a black screen...

Comment: Also, a side note - The flow of my app is Main Menu Scene -> Character Select Scene -> Game Scene. Right now, sitting on either the Main Menu Scene or Character Select Scene keeps the memory at a static level (~108mb due to complex background layers, etc). But as soon as I go to the game scene, even with everything disabled and just a black screen, it grows about .1mb per second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so it turns out the issue is an Apple Bug when 'showsPhysics' is enabled. Turning this off immediately fixed my problem. Thanks @SklyerLauren.

Comment: Sometimes this will solve a memory leak but it is not needed and often hides another issue. When you present a new scene it will get automatically released unless there is a retain cycle. My best guess is you were using self. in a closure or block. Once you removed that action you no longer have the leak. Long story short if you use self (instead of weak self) scene->SKActionBlockWithSelf SKActionBlockWithSelf<-Scene and it can never be released. Hopefully that helps because not knowing why you were leaking usually causes issues in the future =)

Comment: @SkylerLauren Thanks for the feedback. It seems I was mistaken, for some reason the memory usage stopped growing for a while, but now its still climbing .1mb every second, even with everything disabled in the game scene and nothing but a black screen. This is the only scene I have this problem with, all the others work just fine. So weird.

Comment: Most likely and that is a legitimate Apple Bug and has been reported. Super frustrating to troubleshoot too unless you happen to run across someone who has heard about it.

Comment: Ahhhh that was it! Gosh that is annoying. Well now I know... Looks like my app is actually pretty good now once I disabled that.